# react material-ui styled-components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I have built an app which shows orders that are fetched from my api. orders have some properties as shown here:

```
id(pin): 22
open(pin): "3.60000000"
high(pin): "4.50000000"
low(pin): "3.20000000"
close(pin): "4.10000000"
time(pin): "2022-07-30T15:12:00+04:30"
active(pin): false
staged(pin): "OFFTRACK"
```

and I use styled components to show these as follow:

```
const StyledTableRow = styled(TableRow)(({ theme }) => ({
  '&:nth-of-type(odd)': {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover,
  },
  // hide last border
  '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': {
    border: 0,
  },
}));
```

actually my orders has three different values in respect to `staged` property of the order; namely: `ontrack`, `offtrack` and `staged`. I wanted to apply this logic in a way those `StyledTableRow`s could have different styles according to the `staged` property.

and the part I placed the component:

```
{orders.map((order, index) => {
  return (
    <StyledTableRow key={index}>
      <StyledTableCell align="center">{order.open}</StyledTableCell>
      <StyledTableCell align="center">{order.high}</StyledTableCell>
      <StyledTableCell align="center">{order.low}</StyledTableCell>
      <StyledTableCell align="center">{order.close}</StyledTableCell>
    </StyledTableRow>
  )
})}
```

I'm not that new to @mui but about styled components totally confused. thanks.

Comment: Pass `order.staged` as a prop on your styled components and then read it in as another parameter along with `theme`. Style according to the value of the passed prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

morganney's comment is correct, but could use some illustration:

#### Pass order.staged as a prop on your styled components

```js
<StyledTableCell align="center" staged={ order.staged }>{order.high}</StyledTableCell>
```

#### read it in as another parameter along with theme

```js
const StyledTableRow = styled(TableRow)(({ theme, ...props }) => ({
  '&:nth-of-type(odd)': {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover,
  },
  // hide last border
  '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': {
    border: 0,
  },

  // Style according to the value of the passed prop. For example...
  [<selector>]: {
    <CSS_property>: props.staged == "OFFTRACK"
      ? <CSS_property_value_for_offtrack>
      : props.staged == "ONTRACK"
        ? <CSS_property_value_for_ontrack>
        : <CSS_property_value_for_staged> // "STAGED"
  }
  ...
}));
```

Comment: thank you @kofeigen . it was the exact instruction I was looking for and solved my problem